# My method of two factor auth is correct and secure?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, next.js, two-factor-authentication

Hello i have a site and I would like to add two factor auth if user want needs that.
I use nextjs framework and for authentification I use iron-session.

I wanted to know if the system I started to do is correct and secure.

In my page I have I formLogin component and by default (with useState) I display form login :

```
    const [displayInput, setDisplayInput] = useState(false);
```

User can fill in fields (password and email) and call api route.

If user log without two factor that's the answer (after email and password check in back) :

```
    let userObject = {
        role: user.role,
        id: user.id,
    };
    req.session.user = userObject;
    await req.session.save();
    return res.status(200).json({
        status: 200,
        body: userObject,
        message: `Hello, ${user.firstname} you are log`,
    });
```

So the difference when user have two factor auth enable that's I only return this as an answer and I do not create session :

```
    return res.status(200).json({
        status: 200,
        body: null,
    });
```

And I my formLogin component if `response.status === 200 and response.body === null` when user call api route then I call new api route for create and send a code to his email (code is store in database)
If response of new api route is status 200 I change `setDisplayInput(true)` for display input code so that the user enters his code

Then user call api when form is submit with code input and I put in the body of the request email, password and code

In the api route I check again email and password and if user is found I check if code is good and after I can create the session :

```
    req.session.user = userObject;
    await req.session.save();
```

I feel like repeating myself between the two api route because when I have to check the code then I check the password and email again.

I don't know if I made myself clear. If you need more precision on my system don't hesitate.
Thank's